# Getting access token as Null in Google service account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-oauth

I am using Google service account to get access Token from service side using below code. But I am getting access token as Null. The same returned token will be used to open Google file picker on client side for the same userEmailId. Please suggest what I am doing wrong in my code.

```
private static final List SCOPE = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");

public String getAccessToken(String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH,String userEmailId){
                try {
                    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                    JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                                                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                                                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                                                    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                                                    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
                                                    .setServiceAccountUser(userEmailId)
                                                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                                                    .build();

                    credential.getRefreshToken();
                    return credential.getAccessToken();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    log.severe("Error while getting Drive  credentilas. 5.0"+ e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what's wrong here but I'd highly recommend using https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials anyway. If that fails try filing an issue on the cliet lib. https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client

Comment: @BillPrin: Thanks for your comment, actually I am using domain wide delegation as well but getting access token as Null with above code while impersonating a user from server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  The answer seems to be to simply change from
 `credential.getRefreshToken()` 
to simply 
`credential.refreshToken()`

That should solve the issue

Answer (score 9):

For those using the Firebase Admin SDK, hence the GoogleCredentials class, this will do.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount).createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));
credentials.refresh();
credentials.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: If this code is called very often, you could use credentials.refreshIfExpired() instead of credentials.refresh(), to prevent performance issues.